# shared resource without synchronization successded

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

in the below code, CWriteData class writes data to the file, and CBelowThreshold reads the same file and print some data, and CAboveThreshold also reads the same file and prints some
data.

I expected the code to crash as i am NOT using the synchronized block, but when i run the code it works normally.

can you please explain why code despite a file is shared among three threads and there is no synchronization, it did not crash

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    file = IOCtrl.createFile("sharedRes.txt", "c:" + File.separator);

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

    //synchronized (file) {
        executor.schedule(new CWriteData(file), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //}

    //synchronized (file) {
        executor.schedule(new CBelowThreshold(file), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //}

    //synchronized (file) {
        executor.schedule(new CAboveThreshold(file), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it *should* crash?

Comment: @AndyTurner because the same file is accssible by three threads

Comment: You're not showing the *relevant* code, and you don't seem to understand `synchronized` based on your attempts to use it.

Comment: ....and why do you think that three threads accessing the same file should crash? There is nothing inherently wrong with multiple threads having a reference to a file (or anything else, for that matter) - what is the mechanism by which one thread tries to do something, finds it can't because of what another thread is doing/has done, and "crashes"?

Comment: @AndyTurner what if i two threads triy to awrite to the same file, would it be a scenario where synchronization is a demand?

Comment: Yes, you might well want synchronization there; but it doesn't mean that it would crash without it.

Comment: @AndyTurner is there any way to set thread priority when using ExecutorService

Comment: Also note, even if your program needs `synchronized` blocks to guarantee that it does the right thing, taking them out won't guarantee that it will do the wrong thing.  A real-world program with concurrency bugs can pass through QA, be shipped to customers, and run for a year or two in the field before anybody even realizes that there is a problem.  (Don't ask me how I know!)

Comment: `ExecutorService` is an interface.  You may be able to control the priorities of certain _implementations_ of `ExecutorService`.  For example, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class has a constructor that accepts a `ThreadFactory` argument.  You can access the threads by providing your own custom `ThreadFactory`.  But...

Comment: ...If you think you need to control thread priorities, and you're not writing a real-time, embedded system that runs on a specialized real-time JVM, on a real-time OS, then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you actually need thread priorities, or simply to wait until the `CWriteData` has finished before starting the others?